# Run servers behind double-nat or firewall using OpenVPN

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, openvpn, nat

I have the following:

1. A laptop behind double-NAT or Firewall
2. A Cloud Server with full access to the outside world (AWS/Azure etc.) that I can install an OpenVPN Server on

On my laptop I run various TCP/UDP based servers such as HTTP, FTP and various game servers and even servers I wrote myself.

My laptop at home is connected to an ISP that has its own NAT which I can't control to do port forwarding. I also take it to hotels, Starbucks etc. where the internal firewall will not allow me to expose my laptop's servers out to the internet.

How can I use my Cloud server to expose servers running on my laptop to the internet using OpenVPN?